# Scheduled backup and clone of Ubuntu USB live

Tags: backup, live-usb

I created a USB live with Ubuntu and works just great. However, I would want to know how to master this portable solution.

My first concern is data lose (maybe the stick gets lost, maybe damaged) so would love to be able to sync all my data from the usb ubuntu live on ubuntu one. Therefore, every-time I run from the stick and have an internet connection, to sync all my changes for the system to the cloud, so if I get it lost, to be able to install a fresh ubuntu then just select a restore point from ubuntu one.

Second thing : would be great to easily clone all data from usb stick to another one (I want to buy a high speed usb stick). If first option can be done, then you can easily buy a faster usb stick, install ubuntu fresh, then just restore your settings from the cloud.

Is it possible to have this control over your ubuntu usb live ?

I think would be a great solution.

Thank you.

Comment: If I backup the System files folder, is that going to restore all my settings in case my data is lost ? And if I install a new Ubuntu on a different usb stik, and restore this backup, will restore all my settings on the usb stick _ I want to be sure that's why am asking you guys.

Comment: Actually what folders from file system to backup in order to be able to restore later on all my settings and the apps i installed ?